# Linux chmod command error: chmod: invalid mode:

Tags: linux

I want assign the privilege to directory app, my command as below：

```
sudo chmod -R hduser /app
```

`hduser` is username in Linux, however, I got error message:

> chmod: invalid mode: `hduser'

anything need update?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the command you're searching for is `chown`.

http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/chown1.html

Enter somethink like :

```
sudo chown -R username[:groupname] /app
```